# Word phrase, or idiom that describes when you compare yourself or circumstance to a fictional character or story

Tags: single-word-requests

I heard a speaker once introduce himself and his wife as "If I'm the Beast then I'd like to introduce to you my Beauty."

Is there a single word to describe this?

Comment: It's *metaphorical*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Thanks. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Metaphorical](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/metaphorical)** (adjective)
>
> You use the word metaphorical to indicate that you are not using words
>   with their ordinary meaning, but are describing something by means of
>   an image or symbol.